# Real-Time Export of Data

Tags: export, files-and-directories

So I was using a Genetic Algorithm to solve a problem. The inherit takes a lot of time to get me to the final answer, so I would like to monitor the process, and export the data real-time. The code is like this:
    gen={somerandomstart}
    inherit=Function[Something]
    NestWhile[inherit,gen,test]
Currently I'm using `save=(Export[somepath,#];#)&`, but this generates a lot of files, and I had to import every file to get the best individual of each generation. Is there a way of writing (and deleting old data) in the same file?

Comment: See `OpenWrite` and friends